# git local branch and origin/master still diverged after git reset --hard

Tags: git, version-control

After doing

```
git reset --hard
```

I expected to see 'HEAD is now at hexNumber' and then 'on branch master....nothing to commit. Instead I see

```
    wb316-mac03:MoodTrack student$ git reset --hard
    HEAD is now at ec11193 preparation for merge
    wb316-mac03:MoodTrack student$ 
    wb316-mac03:MoodTrack student$ git status
    # On branch master
    # Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
    # and have 2 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
    #
    nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I want to be completely overwritten by what's in the remote master (without recloning). Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the commit that you want to reset to:

```
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

`git reset --hard` will just reset to `HEAD` (which was probably `master` in your case).

Comment: I'm looking at the commits on GitHub. Would that be the extremely long number on the commit details page(6e01ab716bd1e9bf325f752af94269745b9fc3dc) or the 10 digit one on the commit history page?

Comment: My bad. It's the long number. The 10 digit number is an abbreviation of the first number.

Comment: Something is wrong with my syntax. Numerous variations give me the error 'unknown revision or path not in the working tree'.

Comment: Perfect. The commit I want to reset to is literally origin/master. There is no need to specify the commit number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want what is in the remote master and do not care what is two ahead on your branch, check out another branch, delete the master and then pull down the remote.

```
git checkout -b master_tmp
git branch -D master
git checkout -t origin/master
git branch -D master_tmp
```

Best of luck.